# Configuration of System.Runtime.Caching vs Enterprise Library 5 caching block

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, enterprise-library-5, .net-4.5

As part of plans to migrate an existing website from .NET 4 to .NET 4.5.1 we have learned that we will need to move from using Enterprise Library 5 to version 6.

We're using the caching block in version 5, but this has been removed from version 6, so we plan ([as recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664753%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)) to refactor our code to use `System.Runtime.Caching` instead.

We would like to ensure that the settings (in `Web.config`) we will for `System.Runtime.Caching` will give us the same (or similar...) behaviour as those we currently use for the Enterprise Library 5 caching block.

The Enterprise Library 5 caching block settings we are currently using are:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="cachingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Configuration.CacheManagerSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
</configSections>
<cachingConfiguration defaultCacheManager="Cache Manager">
  <cacheManagers>
    <add name="Cache Manager"
      type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.CacheManager, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
      expirationPollFrequencyInSeconds="60"
      maximumElementsInCacheBeforeScavenging="1000"
      numberToRemoveWhenScavenging="10"
      backingStoreName="NullBackingStore" />
  </cacheManagers>
  <backingStores>
    <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.BackingStoreImplementations.NullBackingStore, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
      name="NullBackingStore" />
  </backingStores>
</cachingConfiguration>
```

The `System.Runtime.Caching` settings we are planning to use are:

```
<system.runtime.caching>
  <memoryCache>
    <namedCaches>
      <add name="default"
        cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes="10"
        physicalMemoryLimitPercentage="0"
        pollingInterval="00:01:00" />
    </namedCaches>
  </memoryCache>
</system.runtime.caching>
```

Are we on the right track here?

Note that we do not have comprehensive load testing facilities for our website, so are not able to satisfactorily test our use of caching before we release the website.